# Adobe Cirrus (Stratus) doesn't work if user have local network

Tags: flash, adobe, p2p, soundcloud-stratus, adobe-cirrus

I am developing flash p2p chat. It works fine on my friends' computers (they can chat each other), but not on mine. The problem is that I have local network at home, and I think that Flash Player tries to make p2p requests to peers inside my local network.

Can I check if user have local network in AS3 and up the level of network to the WWW?

**Any ideas are welcome!**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set your router to block outgoing UDP packets?
The problem could be the firewall, not the local ip address.

I think this page will help you to figure out and to solve the problem, especially the Firewall traversal section.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/rtmfp_cirrus_app.html

I can't think of any way to determine if user is in local network with flash player on a web browser. But it might be just okay to let user to configure firewall or TURN proxy, or to provide downloadable script/program which does the same thing. :')

Good luck!